# Error 500 with Devise & User Profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

So I have a project that uses Devise and everything was fine until I implemented email confirmation. When a user signs up, they are locked out of their account until they confirm their email. This is fine; however, the user profile is not viewable until they confirm, which seems odd/like a problem. Then I now have one user (out of multiples) that always brings up an Internal 500 Error. Users have signed up and confirmed after this one but there is still an issue. Looking into the Heroku logs, I see:

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass):`

This makes me think that the @user is not being recognized in the system for him, for some odd reason, and I cannot figure out the problem. I've implemented an admin section; however, I have not figured out how to edit other user information yet, so I cannot go into this setup and look myself.

If anyone has some information, please let me know. Obviously the code works but obviously there is a problem too. If you have any information on allowing to view a profile prior to confirmation, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you =)

Joe

Comment: "however, the user profile is not viewable until they confirm, which seems odd/like a problem" Should someone who hasn't been confirmed be able to view a user profile? That would seem *more* odd to me…

Comment: The project is setup so that profiles are viewable by anyone. With this situation I am referring to though, me (a confirmed user) is unable to view the account of a newer user that had not confirmed their account yet. It simply throws up a 500 error. I would think the profile would still appear as to avoid having issues within the site (or am I crazy =P)?

Comment: You're crazy ;) A confirmed account isn't really an account, or else why would it need confirmation? There may be a setting for this, but that would seem to be the reasoning.

Comment: Haha, okay, well then I guess that is something I will have to just deal with. Just odd because most sites still allow you to view a profile even if it's not confirmed. Though this one odd situation, it says the account was confirmed...I will have to pull the database from Heroku to my localhost then and look at the data I suppose.

Comment: Have you dropped the DB and started over. You may have records that are not current with your schema.

Try `rake db:reset`

also make sure your migrations are up to date as well.

Comment: Take a backup first!

Comment: I am over my head and extremely confused now. I would just want to pull the Heroku database to localhost but not erase any of the data. Though I am more concerned as to what the user is able to do to cause this to happen.

Comment: Joe. You have this on heroku? If that's the case, you're going to have to set a default on the current users. 

The real question is did you test before you deployed? Because you pushed changes that create nulls where a "not null" field may be present.

you can heroku into the command line, launch the rails console, and work out the errors from there. don't forget to save your changes. and test test test....

Comment: Can you paste the heroku logs ?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Jdayvie/faf77bd58a1f03b2f1c0 - That is the Heroku Log.

Answer (score 1):

In your logs it looks as if you're calling a .each method on a single user. `each` is used on arrays. your var is singular. 
`<% for user in @user.nearbys(50) %>`

You'll need a @users = User.all in your controller and then change

This will iterate over the array and get your desired input.

Comment: I never changed the validation recently. The only change I have made lately was remove three validations I had to optional fields.

Comment: It is private, so hold on one second and I will send to you.

Comment: The easy answer is I could simply delete the user if needed (as I set that up via my admin), but I just wanted to make sure there was not an issue with the code causing it to happen. Another user just signed up too.

Comment: I'm confused...you fixed the issue? What about google hangouts? =P

Comment: I sent an email to the one listed on your website. I am awaiting yout google hangout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have saved the user's details in a database - connect directly to it and check the details in there and edit them using SQL or via the ORM you're using if needs be. Delete and recreate is obviously a last resort, but may work too.